# Is there a way to split swiper progress bar on sections (like instagram-stories)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I want to create pagination instagram-story-like (React, no Jquery),but have some problems with customizing. Tried to use bullets, but I can't understand how to save previous state of bullet (because I need keep save fill on dot that was before or after swipe).

Can you recommend me something to realize it ? Thanks.

Comment: Cello and welcome. Can you show your code to help you to correct it ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I'm not sure that my code can help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two ways you can handle this

1. Add a new attribute to the story object (like `"isVisited": true` on visit), update this value on visit. so next time you open the story check only for the `isVisited=false` the story if its visited or not, if visited skip and go to the next story card in the
2. Maintain a separate state to save the `visitedStoriesIds`, update this list in similar as above.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to handle this.